# Positive conditional expectation

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

We have a log-normal variable $x = e^{\mu +\sigma w}$, where $w$ is standard normal.
We want to compute $E[(x - K)^{+}\mid z]$.  I'm not sure if I can write it as $E[(x ̃ - K) 1_{\{x ̃- K>0\} }]$, where $x ̃ $  is $x$ conditional on the standard normal variable $z$ and $1$ is the indicator function.

Edit: The initial question was too simplified. Now $w$ and $z$ are different variables.

Comment: Are $\mu$, $\sigma$ and $K$ constants? $z$ determines $x$ exactly.  So the conditional expectation is $(e^{\mu + \sigma z}-K)^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $(Z,W)$ is normal, one knows that $W=aZ+bT$ where $(Z,T)$ is i.i.d. standard normal, $a=\mathrm{Cov}(W,Z)$ and $b=\sqrt{1-a^2}$, hence $X=Y\mathrm e^{\sigma bT}$ where $\mathrm e^{\sigma bT}$ is independent of $Z$ and $Y=\mathrm e^{\mu+\sigma aZ}$ is measurable with respect to the sigma-algebra generated by $Z$.

Thus, $E[(X-K)^+\mid Z]=Y\cdot u(\sigma b,K/Y)$ where $u(t,s)=E[(\mathrm e^{tT}-s)^+]$ for every positive $t$ and $s$. Finally,
$u(t,s)=\mathrm e^{t^2/2}\Phi(t-t^{-1}\log s)-s\Phi(-t^{-1}\log s).$